# Which algorithm shoud I use in the response if I use JWE with Direct key agreement in the request?

Tags: jwe, ecdh

In the context of a rest API request / response there is JWE with the request and another one in the response.

For the request, I'm using Direct Key Agreement (ECDH).
Which algo should I use to respond back another JWE ? dir or ECDH-ES.
Is there any standard about the communication. ( request / response )